# Code running in source doesn't change plot

Tags: r

Am running these lines of code in the source, and then click "Run" in Rstudio.

```
fill_colors <- c()
for(i in 1:length(hotdogs$Country) ) {
  if (hotdogs$Country[i] == "United States") {
    fill_colors <- c(fill_colors, "#821122")
  } else {
    fill_colors <- c(fill_colors, "cccccc")
  }
}
```

The code gets passed down to the console, but for some reason, the plot doesn't change.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're following http://www.cs.odu.edu/~mweigle/cs795/barchart-r.html:

I suspect you haven't run the line directly after it, which is:

```
barplot(hotdogs$Dogs.eaten, names.arg=hotdogs$Year, col=fill_colors, 
        border=NA, xlab="Year", ylab="Hot dogs and buns (HDB) eaten")
```

Running only the lines you've given will generate a vector `fill_colors`, but you need to use that as a parameter for `fill` in `barplot`.

Comment: That's exactly right.  I needed to pass fill_color as an argument to barplot(). Once I did that, everything ran OK. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you used `fill_colors` earlier as you created your plot, and you are now redefining the `fill_colors` vector.

Plots in R are not dynamically linked to data as they are in other applications like Excel for example (in automatic recall mode). So you need to recreate your plot using the new `fill_colors` as it won't update on its own.

Also, you might find `ifelse` useful. The code above can just be written as:

```
fill_colors <- ifelse(hotdogs$Country == "United States", "#821122", "cccccc")
```